# VB.net No Prompt for User Downloads using Response.Flush

Tags: asp.net, excel, vb.net, file-io

I'm attempting to allow a user to download an excel file created in VB.net using Workbook/Worksheet objects.  The creation of the excel file is complet but the next is to allow a user to download it when they click a button.  I've coded what I believe is the desired method using Response however when I click on the button the download event (tested on Chrome/IE) doesn't happen.  It's as if I never pressed the button but it runs through the code during debug.

```
Protected Sub btnMatrixSummary_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMatrixSummary.Click
    Dim refNum As Integer = employee_LB.SelectedValue

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)

    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")
    xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 2) = "1. Displays High Integrity & Honesty"

 '----------FILL REST OF EXCEL FILE HERE---------------------

  'Prepare download file
    Dim folder As String = Path.GetTempPath

    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(folder & "Matrix.xlsx")
    Dim filePath As System.IO.FileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(xlWorkBook.FullName)

    xlWorkBook.Close(True, misValue, misValue)
    xlApp.Quit()

    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlApp)

    Response.ClearHeaders()
    Response.Clear()
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Matrix6.xls")
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", filePath.Length.ToString())
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls"
    Response.WriteFile(filePath.FullName)

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush() 'Sends all currently buffered output To the client.
    HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = True 'Gets Or sets a value indicating whether To send HTTP content To the client.
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()

    'Delete local matrix off server
     My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(filePath.FullName)
```

Comment: Have you tried logging? Such as try catch and log the errors? I am assuming that the is ASP.net

Comment: @codeMonger123 Tried that as well, it runs to completion with no errors yet the Response doesn't get recognized client side.
I assumed it was listed as ASP after some fields I filed out.

Comment: Where is the file being written to? The server? Also how large is your excel file?

Comment: @codeMonger123 It's being written to a temp folder, so would be a temp folder on the server.  Even if I write it to a local directory I can't even get it to download from there during local testing.  The excel is rather small, maybe 27 rows of data by 7 columns.